# How can I pass string parameter to powershell in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, powershell-3.0

[This project is parameterized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByiYi.png)

[Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znmYD.png)

When I am printing the value of "echo $Branch" & "echo $branch_name", it is showing me empty.Its printing the value 1 - "echo $A". Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine - echo $($env:Branch)

Answer (score 0):

To access parameterised variable you need to access by `params.<Name of your variable`> 
So in your case you need to access as:
 `echo "Branch is : ${params.Branch}"`